# int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter fetch in sequential order?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

How can i make int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter to fetch the files in the order they are created on the remote system ?

for example :

```
File1 - 15:31:01
File2 - 15:32:02
File3 - 15:33:03
File4 - 15:34:04
File5 - 15:35:05
```

Assume my application is down for 5 minutes, with in this time 5 files got created, once i restart/redeploy my application, int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter has to fetch the files to my local system in the order they are created(timestamp).

Please suggests.

Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 2):

The `<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>` has `comparator` attribute:

```
<xsd:attribute name="comparator" type="xsd:string">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
        Specify a Comparator to be used when ordering Files. If none is provided, the
        order will be determined by the java.io.File implementation of Comparable.
        ]]></xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:attribute>
```

It is used for an internal `queue`:

```
public FileReadingMessageSource(Comparator<File> receptionOrderComparator) {
    this.toBeReceived = new PriorityBlockingQueue<File>(
            DEFAULT_INTERNAL_QUEUE_CAPACITY, receptionOrderComparator);
}
```

after `FtpInboundFileSynchronizer` pulls remote files to the local dir before poller starts pick up them for message flow.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have used int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter without comparator attribute, it's picking up the files not in the order they are created, do i need to implement the Comparator with date logic ?. I am new to SI. Please suggest.

Comment: Right, you should implement that `Comparator` to order your files to process.